# How can I efficiently copy over 10,000 sharded tables between GCP projects in Big Query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, database-migration

I am currently working on a migration project for my company where I am tasked to migrate data from one GCP project to another in Big Query. The company that I am doing the migraion for is still using sharded tables and they want to keep it in that format.This means that I need to copy a selection of over 10 000 tables from a dataset in one project over to a dataset in the other project that I am migrating towards. I am relatively new to the GCP environemt and was wondering if anyone is able to give me advice on optimal ways that I can accomplish this. The sharded tables are split between 6 diffrent tables.

Currently the approach that I am considering is writing a dynamic query in big query to use the dataset schema to generate a bunch of cloud shell copy commands. The idea is to export the results of this query to google sheets and then copy these commands into cloud shell in batches.

Comment: What's the source system that currently host those 10k tables?

Comment: The 10k tables are currently stored on big query in a dataset and need to be moved over to another dataset in a diffrent project that is also stored on big query. I hope this answers your question. I am relitvley new to the environment so please feel free to correct me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: All the tables are in the same dataset?

Comment: Yes all the tables are currently stored in the same dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [copy the dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#copy_a_dataset) from your source project to the target